# query on sales for each day and previous sale for each product also

Tags: oracle

I want to show a sales of a product and precious sale of that product also if that product is not sale till date than previous sale column should be null. My source table has id, name, sales_date,quantity and unit_price and resultant table should contain id,name,sales_Date,current_sale (which would contain sale on that day) and previous_sale.The previous sale is for individual product not same for all product.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean with previous sale. Can you edit you question and post some sample data en outcome?

Comment: I mean like there a product p1 which is sold on 24 july and another one is sold on 28 july than the sale of p1 24 july should come previous sale column of 28 july. also before 24 July there is no sell of p1 than previous sale column should be null for p1 product. In answer I want two column a current sale having sale on the particular day and previous sale having sale of that particular product before that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have these data in your table:

```
  ID NAME  SALES_DATE  QUANTITY     UNIT_PRICE
---- ----- ----------- -------- --------------
   1 p1    2015-07-24        10           5,00
   2 p2    2015-07-24        14          10,00
   3 p1    2015-07-28        15           4,00
   4 p2    2015-07-29         7          11,00
   5 p3    2015-07-29         3           2,00
```

This query, using function [lag()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm), generates output you described (plus column previous_sales_date):

```
select id, name, sales_date, unit_price*quantity current_sale, 
    lag(sales_date) over (partition by name order by sales_date) prev_date, 
    lag(unit_price*quantity) over (partition by name order by sales_date) prev_sale
  from sales order by name, sales_date
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98747/1)</sup>

I used partition by name, but if in input table "id" means "product id" it's better to use partition by id.

Output:

```
  ID NAME  SALES_DATE  CURRENT_SALE PREV_DATE    PREV_SALE
---- ----- ----------- ------------ ----------- ----------
   1 p1    2015-07-24            50             
   3 p1    2015-07-28            60 2015-07-24          50
   2 p2    2015-07-24           140             
   4 p2    2015-07-29            77 2015-07-24         140
   5 p3    2015-07-29             6
```

---

**Edit:** If there are many entries for product per day you need some form of aggregation, most obvious is sum, 
like in example below. You can also use min, max, avg.

```
select name, sales_date, sale current_sale, cnt, 
    lag(sales_date) over (partition by name order by sales_date) prev_date, 
    lag(sale) over (partition by name order by sales_date) prev_sale,
    lag(cnt) over (partition by name order by sales_date) prev_cnt 
  from (
    select name, trunc(sales_date) sales_date, sum(unit_price*quantity) sale, count(1) cnt
      from sales group by name, trunc(sales_date)
    )
  order by name, sales_date
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe300/2)</sup>

I also added columns `cnt` and `prev_cnt` - showing number of rows for that product in current and previous days.

Comment: I want to ask if there is product which has two entries on a same day means it is sold on a same day how can I show only one entry of that product in the resultant table

Comment: but the thing is your query is showing product in multiple rows that are being sold in same day. I want like if p1 is sold on 30-7-2015 and another p1 is sold on same day than there should not be multiple entries in resultant table.

Comment: my source table has sales_Date in timestamp data type if that would help

Comment: Please replace `sales_date` with `trunc(sales_date)` in inner query (like in edited answer).

Comment: Its just making date shorter not merging the sales of the product that is product with same sale date is showing in different rows

Comment: So now I'm not sure what you want - probably replace `sum(sales_date)` with `max(sales_date)` in inner query but only in select list (not in group by). See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7424c/1). Notice that for product p3, for last date, there are multiple entries and query is gouping them, showing last date and time.
If this is not what you want - please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31692064/edit) your question and show example input, expected output and query you used otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: Yes, but analytic functions (here it's `lag()`) are better alternative. Otherwise we could make self-join with condition like `prev_date<current`, order them properly and take only first match. Code would be longer and execution time - slower. But maybe you are asking about joining other tables - if so I propose you to ask new question on main forum.

Comment: No. Join should be on this table just want to check whether there is a way through ANSI standard

Comment: There is a way - here is my try: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c068/1). 
First query is with lag() functions, second operates on joins. Second query uses [CTE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) to avoid repetitive code.
I added one row to data to complicate things slightly and compare results.